# Adding elements to JSON document

Tags: javascript, json

I have initialized a JSON document in my code like this:

```
var json = [];
```

I use the '.push()' method to add elements to this document like this:

```
json.push({title: "abc", link: "xxx"});
```

In the end I get a JSON document that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "title": "abc",
    "link": "xxx"
  }
  {
    "title": "asd",
    "link": "zzz"
  }
  ...
]
```

This is not entirely bad, but I wanted it to look like this:

```
{
  "links":
    [
      {
        "title": "abc",
        "link": "xxx"
      }
      {
        "title": "asd",
        "link": "zzz"
      }
      ...
    ]
}
```

Any ideas how I can make it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing

```
var json = [];
```

You initialize an array, not an object.

To have an object you can do:

```
var json = {};
```

Then to add a field:

```
json.links = [];
```

then push to you links object:

```
json.links.push({title: "abc", link: "xxx"});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var json = {};
 json.links = [];
 json.links.push({title: "abc", link: "xxx"});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var json = {
  links: []
};
json.links.push({title: "abc", link: "xxx"});
```